# IceFaces - server side sort column extraction

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have a simple `ace:dataTable` component with the following sort listener:

`<ace:ajax event="sort" execute="@this" render="@all" listener="#{userModel.myListener}"/>`

On server side I have the following listener:

```
public void myListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent ajaxBehaviorEvent){
//todo extract sort column name
}
```

How can I extract the current sort column value in the listener? I can extract the source of the `AjaxBehaviorEvent`, which is a `DataTable`, and it has a `getSortCriteria()` method, which returns, what I want, but it is protected, so I can't use it. Are there other options?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the columns of the `DataTable` using `getColumns()` method. If `Column.hasSortPriority()` is true, then this column is selected as an order criteria. You can use `Column.isSortAscending()` to determine the direction of the ordering.